# php some image files cannot be uploaded

Tags: php

I have some problem with image uploads. I have checked all posts on stackoverflow about this issue and tried everything that people recommended in comments but nothing works.

Most images files works just fine to upload but some files just wont work. For example some jpg files works and some jpg files doesnt. And same for png and all other file extensions.

First i thought it was about the size but i increased size to 500000000 and it still doesnt work... So i was thinking maybe its the upload limit in php.ini.

I tried to raise up the limit and also uncomment the limit and restart apache but it still wont work. So what is the problem?

Here is my upload script

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "GIF", "JPEG", "JPG", "PNG");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 500000000) &&
in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

  echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";

}else{

  $fileName = $temp[0].".".$temp[1];
  $temp[0] = rand(0, 3000);
  $fileName;

  if (file_exists("../../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";

  }else{

    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../../uploads/" . $newfilename)) {
      include('../config/dbconf.php');
      $title = $_POST['title'];
      $content = $_POST['content'];
      $sticky = $_POST['sticky'];
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO gallery (img_name, title, content, sticky) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
      $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $newfilename, $title, $content, $sticky);
      if($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded. You will be redirected back to upload page !";
        header('refresh:2; ../upload');
      }else{
        echo $stmt->error;
      }
    }

  }

}

}else{
  echo "Invalid File : " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . $_FILES["file"]["type"];
}
?>
```

Comment: Does the image get uploaded to your directory? Does it pass the In_array check??  Try and debug every instance

Comment: It returns "Invalid File : <filename>"

Comment: And no. It does not get uploaded to the folder so it does not pass the in_array check

Comment: Debug every condition you have. Use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) and tell us: what is the value of `$extension`, what is the value of `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` and what is the value of `$_FILES["file"]["size"]`?

Comment: Hmm... Okey. This is even more weird. I added error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top and tried again and now it uploads. It cannot be because of the error reporting lol. But i have not changed anything else since last time i tried and now it works...